# Appending lists from files to a single list in Python

Tags: python, list, io

I'm trying to write a function that reads files from a "deferred" directory which contains files that contain lists. Here's what the files in the deferred folder contain:

```
'173378981', '45000', '343434', '3453453', '34534545', '3452342', '234234', '42063008', 'Exempted', '10000'
'1000014833', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'Exempted', '0'
'1000009598', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'Exempted', '0'
'279483421', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'Exempted', '0'
'1000009600', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'Exempted', '0'
'389453080', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'Exempted', '0'
'1000009602', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'Exempted', '0'
```

The function used to write the file(s):

```
def storeDeferredRecords(records):
    """docstring for createFile"""
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    filename = deferredDir + '/' + now.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    f = open(filename, 'w')
    newlist = map(lambda(x): str(x)[1:-1], records)
    for item in newlist:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
    f.close
```

I need help with the function used to read the file. I was only able to write this:

```
def getDeferredRecords():
        """docstring for getDeferredRecords"""
        infiles = [infile for infile in glob.glob(deferredDir + '/*')]
                <code to read the contents of each file here>
```

Can someone help me out? I need to read the lines and insert them into a list. This list will then be merged with records from separate CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html):

```
BigList = []
for filename in glob.glob(deferredDir + '/*'):
    PartList = csv.reader(open(filename))
    BigList.extend(PartList)
```

Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Thanks Tim. I'm already using the CSV module to read the initial source file. The files inside the "deferred" folder were created from the initial source file.

Comment: Yes, this is what I had in mind. Thanks also for making me realize that I can use csv.reader as well to load the list into the "big list."

Answer (score 2):

First, the last line in the store function needs to be like this `f.close()`

Your store function saves the values in a newline-separated manner. To read all the files, should be enough:

```
def getDeferredRecords():
    """docstring for getDeferredRecords"""
    return dict((infile, list(iter(file(infile)))) 
                     for infile in glob.glob(deferredDir + '/*'))
```

Explanation: a file is iterable, so you can do `for line in file: print line` for example. With `list(iter(file))` you have the lines of a file in a list. `dict((a, b) for a, b in foo)` returns a dictionary with `{a: b}` pairs. The return value of the function is a dictionary with the format `{filename: list_of_lines_in_file}`. Keep in mind that the list elements are strings with a trailing newline.

Comment: Replace '''return dict((infile, list(iter(infile))''' with '''return dict((infile, list(iter(infile)))'''    Right parenthesis was missing after list(iter(infile)).

Comment: *sigh* there is always something - replaced `infile` with `file(infile)` and fixed parenthesis - thanks abgan

Answer (score 1):

The Python `cvs` module is likely a good answer:
http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

**Question:**

`glob.glob()` returns an iterable already, so I do not see the point here...

```
[infile for infile in glob.glob(deferredDir + '/*')]
```

Rather:

```
BigList = []
for filename in glob.glob(deferredDir + '/*'):
    #CVS read code here
    #add to BigList
```

Food for thought.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! However, there will be X number of files inside the "deferred" directory. I need to go through each file, read the contents to the list, and append it to the big list.

Answer (score 0):

Incorporating ideas from Tim Pietzcker, here are the re-written functions:

```
def storeDeferredRecords(records):
    """docstring for createFile"""
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    filename = deferredDir + '/' + now.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    f = csv.writer(open(filename, 'w'), delimiter=',')
    f.writerows(records)

def getDeferredRecords():
    """docstring for getDeferredRecords"""
    for filename in glob.glob(deferredDir + '/*'):
        def_records = csv.reader(open(filename,'r'))
        records.extend(def_records)
```

I used csv.writer instead of using the previous code block:

```
f = open(filename, 'w')
newlist = map(lambda(x): str(x)[1:-1], records)
for item in newlist:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
f.close
```

Thanks to all those who replied!

Comment: Learned 2 new lessons today: you can use list.extend(list) to "append" a list to another list and use csv.writer instead of writing your own function to write a comma-separated list to a file.

Comment: Thanks also to @gahooa for pointing out that I no longer need to use a list comprehension to walk through the directory using glob.glob().